# ways for getting incremental data into apache kylin from hive?

Tags: kylin

Anybody knows about,what are the different ways for getting incremental data from hive into apache kylin fact and dimension tables?
please suggest me....I tried a lot lot.But my curl command not able to get hive fact table incremental data into kylin fact table.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Kylin is designed to do incremental data load from day one. It is straightforward and shall work with all data sources, not just Hive. Key points are:

- [Create a partitioned data model](http://kylin.apache.org/docs20/tutorial/create_cube.html). Make sure the "Partition Date
  Column" is set correctly in the model's "Settings" tab.
- [Build cube by selecting a time range](http://kylin.apache.org/docs20/tutorial/cube_build_job.html). Given a partitioned model, you will be
  prompted for a time range when building cube. Make sure that appears.
- Then further build on the same cube will prompt for incremental time
  range.
- [Incremental build can also trigger from RestAPI](http://kylin.apache.org/docs20/howto/howto_build_cube_with_restapi.html) by providing continuous time ranges.